# Select specific td using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to select a specific td Value from this table:

```
<div id="mangaproperties">
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><h2> Ichiba Kurogane</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alternate Name:</td>
<td>Wants to Earn Income</td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Now what i want to get is this td value:

```
<td>Wants to EarnIncome</td>
```

I have tried this code:

```
var div3 = document1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='mangaproperties']/table/*/tr[1]/td[1]");
```

But iit's not worked for me .. Can someone let me know how i can get the specified td value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `tr[2]/td[2]` instead of `tr[1]/td[1]`, because the paser started with `1` instead of `0`

```
var div3 = document1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='mangaproperties']/table/*/tr[2]/td[2]");
```

Then you can use to get the value.

```
div3.FirstOrDefault().InnerText
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qbU5Wn)